# Intent from Activity 1 to Activity 2 then Intent from Activity 2 to Activity 1 without reseting the listview

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

Is there any way to intent Activity A to B then Intent Activity B to A without using onBackPressed?

I want to achieve something like on backpressed where when you go back to Activity A, the listview will not reset to the top list..

Comment: Hello. Have you considered using startActivityForResult, instear of startActivity, and than handling the result according to your needs?
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `finish()`.